# How do I get the current userId to link it with the foreignkey of my product Model in Django Rest-framework & Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, django-rest-auth

i am struggling with getting my User ID after i log in. The token is and already stored in localstorage

working on Django as backend and Vue.js as frontend

so a user is able to login and out but I can't seem to find the userId of the logged in user
in able to retrieve more data linked to the user.

Therefore i cannot post an product properly related to a user. besides that, if i manage to post and check via console on chrome, it says my category section null/empty

Whenever I try to link my category foreignfield in the product model 
i keep getting this error below

```
{category: ["Invalid hyperlink - No URL match."]}
category: ["Invalid hyperlink - No URL match."]
0: "Invalid hyperlink - No URL match.
```

Thanks in advance

my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# class User(models.Model):
#     id_user = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
#     def __str__(self):
#        return self.id_user

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True,)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class State(models.Model):

    STATE_CHOICES = [('Ordered', 'Ordered'), ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Placed', 'Placed'), ('Reserved', 'Reserved')
    ]
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True,
    choices = STATE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.state

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=800, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    #image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_image', blank=True, width_field=None, height_field=None, max_length=100,)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user','title'),)
        index_together = (('user','title'),) 


    # CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    #     ('Books', 'Books'),
    #     ('eBooks','eBooks'),
    #     ('Writing material','Writing material'),
    # )
    # category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)



    SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        ('Erasmushogeschool | EHB',(
            ('Campus Kaai', 'Campus Kaai'),
            ('Campus Bloemberg', 'Campus Bloemberg'),
        )),
        ('Vrije Universiteit Brussel | VUB',(
            ('Campus Jette', 'Campus Jette'),
            ('Campus Schaarbeek', 'Campus Schaarbeek'),
        )),
        ('Katholieke universiteit leuven | KUL',(
            ('KUL Gent', 'KUL Gent'),
            ('Campus Antwerpen', 'Campus Antwerpen'),
        )),
    )
    school = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SCHOOL_CHOICES, null=True)

    MAJOR_CHOICES = (
        ('IT','IT'),
        ('Marketing','Marketing'),
        ('DIFF','DIFF'),
    )
    major = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=MAJOR_CHOICES, null=True)

    SUBJECT_CHOICES = [
        ('Mathematics','Mathematics'),
        ('Algoritmes','Algoritmes'),
        ('Analyses','Analyses'),
    ]
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, null=True)

    CONDITION_CHOICES = [
        ('New','New'),
        ('Used','Used'),
    ]
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=CONDITION_CHOICES, null=True)

    LOCATION_CHOICES = [
        ('Brussel','Brussel'),
        ('Leuven','Leuven'),
        ('Gent','Gent'),
        ('Antwerpen','Antwerpen'),
    ]
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product, State, Category
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password':{'write_only':True,'required':True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
      user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
      print(user)
      Token.objects.create(user=user)
      return user


class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.CharField(source='category.name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'


class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name')

class StateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from django.urls import path
from restapi.views import ProductViewSet, StateViewSet, UserViewSet, CategoryViewSet

# class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
#     class Meta:
#         model = User
#         fields = ['id', 'url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff']

# # ViewSets define the view behavior.
# class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
#     queryset = User.objects.all()
#     serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet)
router.register('product', ProductViewSet)
router.register('category', CategoryViewSet)
router.register('state', StateViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
 ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from  rest_framework import viewsets, status
from .models import Product, State, Category
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializer import ProductSerializer, UserSerializer, StateSerializer, CategorySerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated,AllowAny
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter, OrderingFilter
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_calsses = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('title', 'price', 'category__name')

    # def delete(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    #     response = {'message':'product cannot be updated like this'}
    #     return Response(response, status = statu.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # def create(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    #     response = {'message':'product cannot be created like this'}
    #     return Response(response, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_calsses = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('name', 'id')

class StateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
    permission_calsses = (IsAuthenticated,)

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = User.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserSerializer
  authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
  permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

# class CustomObtainAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
#     def post(self, request, args, *kwargs):
#         response = super(CustomObtainAuthToken, self).post(request, args, *kwargs)
#         token = Token.objects.get(key=response.data['token'])
#         return Response({'token': token.key, 'id': token.user_id})
```

my front end Vue.js login

```
<template>
 <div class="login-form">
          <b-form @submit.prevent="login" v-if="token==null">
            <div class="sign-in-htm">
              <div class="group">
                <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
                <input id="user" type="text" class="input" required v-model="username">
              </div>
              <div class="group">
                <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
                <input
                  id="pass"
                  type="password"
                  class="input"
                  data-type="password"
                  v-model="password"
                  required>
              </div>

some more code...
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: "login",
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      user_id : 0,
            password: '',
            repeat: '',
      submitted: false,
      token: null,
      log_status: ''
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    login() {
      axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.token = res.data.token;
          this.log_status = "Log out";
          this.$root.$emit("logAndToken", this.log_status, this.token);
          console.log(
            "Login data:",
            res,
            this.username,
            this.password,
            this.token
          );
          localStorage.setItem("logAndToken", this.token);
          localStorage.setItem("user_id", this.user_id);
        });
        this.$router.push({ name: "homepage" }).catch(err => {
        localStorage.removeItem("logAndToken");
        localStorage.removeItem("user_id");
        console.log("error loginn", err);

      });
    },
    register() {
      console.log(this.username);
      axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
this.submitted = true;
        this.$validate()
          .then(function(success) {
            if (success) {
              alert('Validation succeeded!');
            }
          });
      this.$router.push({ name: "useradmin" });
        },
       submit: function () {
        this.submitted = true;
        this.$validate()
          .then(function(success) {
            if (success) {
              alert('Validation succeeded!');
            }
          });
      }

</script>
```

my navbar at the top | in this component i check whether i have an token or not with the v-for

```
<template>

 <li class="nav-item dash">
                 <a  class="nav-link pr-2 h5 font-weight-bold" type="button" @click.prevent="$router.push({ name: 'useradmin' }).catch(err => {})" v-if="this.token!=null">Dasboard</a>
            </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
                 <a  class="nav-link pr-2 h5" type="button" @click.prevent="$router.push({ name: 'sdf' }).catch(err => {})" v-if="this.token!=null" v-on:click="logout()" >{{this.log_status}}</a>
            </li> 
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link pr-2 h5" type="button" @click.prevent="$router.push({ name: 'sdf' }).catch(err => {})" v-if="this.token==null">{{this.log_status}}</a>
            </li>

// more code

</template>

<script>

var url_category = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/'

export default {
  name: "Menu",
  components: {},
  props: [],
  data() { 
    return {
      categories:[],
      title: '',
      token: null,
      log_status: this.token?'log out':'log in',
    };

  }, 
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('logAndToken', (log_status, token)  => {
      this.token = token
      this.log_status = log_status
      console.log('message received from login + token' ,log_status, token);
    })
  },
  methods: {
   sendCategoryName(category_name){
   this.$root.$emit('message', category_name)

   },
  logout(){
                    localStorage.removeItem('logAndToken');
                    this.token = null;
                    this.log_status = "Log in"
                    this.$root.$emit('logAndToken', this.log_status, this.token)
            }
  },
    created() {
    axios.get(url_category).then(res => (this.categories = res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log("error", err));


    /*   To check if anything is coming trough, i console log the result:
           .then(res => console.log(res))
           My records were in the array 'results'
          */

    // get the Records form the API use Vue detected tool extention via chrome.
  }
};


 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch user_id from request object. `request.user.id`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store additional information, it's a good idea to utilize JWT tokens. When you send the token from the server you can encode additional information into the response payload.

For example your payload might look like this when its encoded.

```
{
   token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"
}
```

When you decode it from your frontend app

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

Take a look at https://jwt.io/

Right now, it seems like you don't encode any other additional information into your response.